# rails devise separate form login for different roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rolify

I have 2 role:

1. Admin
2. User

I want user with each role can only login using their own form, eg: user with admin role can only login using this url : `/admin`

I can't find any documentation for this. Is there any solution?. thanks